# HttpDelete taking multiple parameters for batch deleting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, react-admin

I'm developing an API that will be consumed by react-admin client application. According to our Frontend developer react-admin supports deleting multiple entities at once by sending HTTP Delete requests like

```
DELETE /api/Entity/Delete?filter={"ids":[1,2,3]}
```

Obviously single id requests are handled well by this method

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
```

But what would be the proper way and the route to handle requests containing multiple ids? Obviously client-side request format is just for demonstration purposes and can be changed if there are any unspoken agreements on that kind of requests.

Answer (score 4):

You can make the parameter an array:

```
[HttpDelete("Delete")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int[] id)
```

Then you call it like this:

```
DELETE /api/Entity/Delete?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

That will populate the `id` array with `{ 1, 2, 3 }`.

Putting JSON in the query string, like your original example (`?filter={"ids":[1,2,3]}`) is possible, but not easy. You have to [handle the binding yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44610433/1202807).

Answer (score 2):

When submitting multiple ids, I find that the best way is to submit them as a JSON array in the body.

So the URL is `/api/Entity/Delete`, and the body:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

You can then receive it:

```
[HttpDelete("/api/Entity/Delete")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete([FromBody] int[] ids)
{
}
```

Comment: Delete verb isn't supposed to take a body, is it ?

Comment: That's true, according to convention the URL should refer to the resource being deleted.