# ASP.NET Core De-serialise IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> from Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json-deserialization

I'm building a RESTful API in ASP.NET Core (3.0). Each controller has a method used to search domain objects which accepts a *List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>* as a querystring parameter defined like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Service.Models.Asset>> Get(
        [FromQuery(Name = "criteria")] List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> criteria,
        [FromQuery] int? page = 0, 
        [FromQuery] int? size = null)
    {
        var dtoList = _assetService.SearchPaged(criteria, page, size);
        return Ok(dtoList);
    }
```

I'm passing the criteria as a JSON serialised string, the request URI is:

```
http://api/asset?criteria=[{"key":"uprn","value":"h1"},{"key":"uprn","value":"h2"}]&page=0&size=100
```

I can't get the controller to accept a value for the criteria parameter, the *criteria* list is always zero-length. I've tried URL encoding the text, makes no difference.

If I change the parameter to a string, I can deserialize the parameter using JsonConvert successfully (same URI).

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Service.Models.Asset>> Get(
        [FromQuery(Name = "criteria")] string criteriaString,
        [FromQuery] int? page = 0, 
        [FromQuery] int? size = null)
    {
        var criteria = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(criteriaString);
        var dtoList = _assetService.SearchPaged(criteria, page, size);
        return Ok(dtoList);
    }
```

I don't want to use model binding with a strongly typed parameter object because I have a generic parameter converter that builds an expression from the criteria list to apply to my EF DbSet. This is applied across a number of different controllers.

Is this possible, or should I give up and stick with my string parameter and manage the de-serialization myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this answer on SO [How to bind Json Query string in asp.net core web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607960/how-to-bind-json-query-string-in-asp-net-core-web-api) you can not bind query params in json format. You need to write your own model binder for deserializing to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Without having done tests, I guess, based on the linked answer, something like this should do the job:

Create the model binder implementation:

```cs
public class KeyValueListModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var jsonString = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key).FirstValue;
        MyCustomModel result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(jsonString);

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Create the provider:

```cs
public class KeyValueListModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>))
            return new KeyValueListModelBinder();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Register the provider in startup:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(config => config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new KeyValueListModelBinderProvider()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I read tonnes of stuff on here about model binding but managed to miss the question you linked in. A custom model binder looks like the way to go, I'll give it a try.